# Grails addTo and removeFrom dynamic methods performance

Tags: grails, grails-orm, dynamicmethod

I have been using Grails addTo and removeFrom dynamic methods and they are awesome, Usually I use them in following way

```
String id =params.quizId
Quiz quizInstance = Quiz.get(Long.parseLong(id))// **1**
for( String q in params.questionCheckBox)
{   
    Question question = Question.get(Long.parseLong(q))//**2**
    quizInstance.addToQuestions(question)//**3**
}
```

Being a person who used to work on java I visualize this piece of code as following three steps

1. run a select query to get quizInstance
2. run a select query to get question
3. run an insert query to insert questions in QUIZ_QUESTION table

I do see that third step only requires just quiz id and and Question id then why to perform first two steps. Is there an "addTo" kind of static method which I can use to say `Quiz.addToQuestionAndQuiz(questionId,QuizId)`
Please correct me if I am wrong in assuming the way things will go on db side.

Also is there a way to add a list of values dirctly using addTo method or must I use a for loop?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you found this chunk of your code to be performing poorly? If not, then why worry about it?

Comment: You can use a HQL statement that differs depending on the relationship, if it's M:M or 1:M.

Comment: @cdeszaq can you convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion - I don't know if this will work correctly or not:

```
String id =params.quizId
List<Question> questionList = Question.findAllByIdInList(params.questionCheckBox)
Quiz quizInstance = Quiz.get(Long.parseLong(id))
quizInstance.questions += questionList
```

Let me know if that works for you